# I can't locate python on mac

Tags: python, macos, terminal, installation

I just installed python 3.6.2.
I then opened the mac terminal and typed:

```
python3 -V
```

and it said: "command not found"

I then changed the directory to the desktop and repeated the same command and it gave the same result. Then i tried:

```
type -a python
```

and it said: python: not found

Comment: Was the built-in version working before the installation?

Comment: Exactly how did you install it?

Comment: I went on the python main website and now I can see it located in my Applications. But when i type python in the mac terminal it says python: command not found

Answer (score 3):

You should firstly add the python executable path to the environment variable $PATH, then you'll be able to run the command wherever you are.

In your terminal:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
export PATH="path-to-your-python-folder:$PATH"
save it and exit (Command + Q)
force execute it with: source ~/.bash_profile
```

Reboot your system, then you should be able to run it.